# Can I split the limit of a sum function?

Tags: calculus, limits

To find the limit from $x$ tend to $2$, can I split this function? So my idea was to search the limit (right and left) of the first part and then search the limit of the other part and then add those two together. 
$$f(x)= \frac{x-3}{x^2-5x+6}+\sqrt{5x+1}$$
Thanks!!!

Comment: I suggest to use the verb *tend* instead of *going*.

Comment: You don't need to edit your question to say "problem solved". If you find a good answer that solves your question, accept the answer (and that sort of finishes the question)

Comment: @Math2174 If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. If both limits exist, then the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits. And if one of the limits exists but the other doesn't, the limit of the sum doesn't exist.

However, if none of the limits exist, you can conclude nothing about the limit of the sum.

Comment: One of the basic "rules" of limits is that, if both $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exist, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)+ g(x)= \lim_{x\to a} f(x)+ \lim_{x\to a} g(x)$.

Comment: @user247327 That's what I wrote, right?!

Comment: But the left and right limit do exist, does that counts too?

Comment: What I wrote applies to left limits, to right limits and to two-sided limits.